# how to set dd-MM-yyyy formate in ajaxToolkit CalendarExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajax Toolkit Calendar Extender.And i need dd-MM-yyyy date formate.
For that i write this code

### Code

```
 <asp:TextBox CssClass="tb10" ID="txtDtFrom" runat="server" Width="130px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgFrom" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/GridViewCSSThemes/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" CausesValidation="False" />
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEdit_dtFrom" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="txtDtFrom"
            Mask="99-99-9999"
            MaskType="Date"
            AcceptAMPM="True"
            DisplayMoney="Left"
            AcceptNegative="Left"
            ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" 
        CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" CultureDateFormat="" 
        CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
        CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" />
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditV_dtFrom" runat="server"
            ControlExtender="MaskedEdit_dtFrom"
            ControlToValidate="txtDtFrom"
            EmptyValueMessage="Date is required"
            InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid"
            Display="Dynamic"
            TooltipMessage="Input a date"
            EmptyValueBlurredText="Date is required"
            InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Date is invalid"
            IsValidEmpty="False"
            ValidationGroup="MKE" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="Cd_dt" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDtFrom" 
            CssClass="red" PopupButtonID="ImgFrom" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" 
        Enabled="True"  />
```

When i select any date it shows blank text box.
And when i use dd/MM/yyyy then it works fine.
So can any one tell me how to achieve dd-MM-yyyy format.

Comment: use `TryParseExact`...

Comment: onlclick of textbox u have to popup calender extender and when select date show date in dd-MM-yyyy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution.
It needs some configuration changes in `.aspx` page or web config.

### In file

```
Culture="en-GB"
```

### In web config

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

In `<system.web>` section of web config file.

Now `Format="dd-MM-yyyy"` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Format="dd-MM-yyyy"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calendarBirthDate" 
        runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtBirthDate" Format="dd-MM-yyyy">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RequiredFieldValidator` instead of `MaskedEditValidator` to validate the required field. Then set the `UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear"` for `MaskedEditExtender` to validate the valid format.

```
    <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEdit_dtFrom" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDtFrom"
        Mask="99-99-9999" MaskType="Date" AcceptAMPM="True" DisplayMoney="Left" AcceptNegative="Left"
        ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder=""
        CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" CultureThousandsPlaceholder=""
        CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDtFrom"
        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Date is required" ValidationGroup="MKE"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="Cd_dt" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDtFrom"
        CssClass="red" PopupButtonID="ImgFrom" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" Enabled="True" />
```